# How to set a scrolling background in a Pane that repeats itself?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm coding a little video game, and in the main menu, I'd like to have the title of the game and all, but in the background, I'd like to have a scrolling background that repeats itself. Like this :

[auto-scrolling example](http://junkerhq.net/xrgb/images/f/f5/Scroll.gif)

This example is kind of what I want, although it roughly come back to its initial state. It's not a correct loop.

Here's another example : [another auto-scrolling loop background](https://mycriticalapproachtotechnologyandsociety.files.wordpress.com/2007/02/cloudsscroll.gif)

I'm using a Pane on which I add my different elements, so the background is one them.

What I already thought of doing was to use two imageView of the same picture, but distinct, and cut them gradually to make the loop/repeat illusion.

The described results would be what I already mentioned above.

Thank you

Comment: You could create a GIF of what you want, then set the image as [the background](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) of your `Pane` (or keep using an `ImageView`).

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this in a card game I wrote that scrolls the cards in the background. This probably won't be exactly how you do it, but it should give you an idea on how to accomplish it.

```
//The containing transition.
SequentialTransition slideshow = new SequentialTransition();
//Set up my array of cards
ImageView[] slides = new ImageView[fileList.length];

for(int i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
    //Populate my array and set up the translate transitions.
    slides[i] = new ImageView(new Image(fileList[i].getPath().substring(19)));
    slides[i].setTranslateX(slides[i].getImage().getWidth());
    //One after the other
    SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition();
    //From right side to middle
    TranslateTransition peekIn = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), slides[i]);
    //Pause in the middle
    PauseTransition stop = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(2000));
    //From middle to left side.
    TranslateTransition peekOut = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), slides[i]);
    //This sets up where the peeks start and finish.
    peekIn.setFromX(slides[i].getImage().getWidth());
    peekIn.setToX(0);

    peekOut.setFromX(0);
    peekOut.setToX(-1*(slides[i].getImage().getWidth()));
    //This is the order that these transitions occur.
    seq.getChildren().addAll(peekIn, stop, peekOut);
    slideshow.getChildren().add(seq);
}
//Previously created background container. (Happens to be a StackPane)
bgContainer.getChildren().addAll(slides);
//I want the Transition to play backwards as well.
slideshow.setAutoReverse(true);
//I want it to never stop
slideshow.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
//I start it.
slideshow.play();
```

So using different types of Transitions I create the effect of scrolling cards in the background of my title screen. You will most likely want to use `TranslateTransition`s along with `SequentialTransition`s to gain the effect you are looking for. Transitions are very interesting classes, and you should research them to see if they are what you want.